# getting a full length window of items in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a long python list and given an index and a max window size, I would like to obtain all the items in this window that include the index. Should be symmetrical as possible, but if not, should contain the max window size number of items. Consider the following example:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] 
index = 1
max_window_size = 7
```

we will result with the list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`
and given the same list and

```
index = 8
max_window_size = 4
```

we will result with the list `[6,7,8,9]`.

Is there a quick method to do that without any loop?

Comment: This seems very arbitrary. Are these one of the possible outputs? In case one your index is on the second position while in the second case, without changing anything else, it's on the third position. Could `[7, 8, 9, 10]`, be a valid output for case 2? or `[8, 9, 10, 11]`?

Comment: is index here position or value in list?

Comment: @PrakharRathi the result should be as symmetrical as possible, meaning the first option you gave is fine.

Comment: You don't need a loop, you can take array slice, like this `my_list[index - max_window_size / 2 : index + max_window_size / 2]`  but you should check that you stay within array bounds.

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov your solution does not solve the first scenario.

Comment: Your question was is it possible to do it w/o a loop. You should first calculate lower and upper indexes, for example `lower = max(0,index-max_window_size/2)`